# Solr custom filter NoSuchMethod exception

Tags: solr

I've read many same questions, but still can't get the answer.

I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SolrCustomFilters.SolrCustomAlarmFilterFactory.<init>(java.util.Map)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:582)
```

while loading Solr

My filter factory:

```java
package SolrCustomFilters;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

public class SolrCustomAlarmFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory  {

    public void init(java.util.Map<String, String> args) {
    }

    protected SolrCustomAlarmFilterFactory(java.util.Map<String, String> args) {
    super(args);
    }

    @Override
    public SolrCustomAlarmFilter create(TokenStream ts) {
    return new SolrCustomAlarmFilter(ts);
    }
}
```

Schema config:

```xml
<analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="SolrCustomFilters.SolrCustomAlarmFilterFactory" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Any suggestions?

P.S. Jars used in filter are the same as in Solr (simply copied).

---

Thinking is difficult...
Made constructor public and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SolrCustomAlarmFilterFactory.<init>` is the constructor and not the `init` method. The constructor should be `public`.